# How to show a div if input field value is empty but contains a variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to display a warning message when the input value is empty. Specifically I want to show a div that contains some text. Everything works fine when the input value is completely empty, but the problem is that my input field contains a variable, so it's not really empty, however the variable can be empty.

I can't figure out how I could get the same result when the variable is present. Can anyone give me guidance on this? I appreciate any help, thank you for any replies.

**This is what is working when value is completely empty**

```js
// Example 1 - value empty and show div 
if(document.getElementById("account_first_name").value == "") {
  document.getElementById("showDiv").style.display="block";
}
```

```html
<!-- Example 1 - value empty and show div -->
<input type="text" class="field-settings" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" 
value=""/>

<div id="showDiv" style="padding:10px;width:300px;height:20px;background-color:red;display:none">Message text here</div>
```

**This is what's not working as my value contains a variable**

```js
// Example 1 - value empty and show div 
if(document.getElementById("account_first_name").value == "") {
  document.getElementById("showDiv").style.display="block";
}
```

```html
<!-- Example 1 - value empty and show div -->
<input type="text" class="field-settings" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" 
value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>"/>

<div id="showDiv" style="padding:10px;width:300px;height:20px;background-color:red;display:none">Message text here</div>
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't know anything about your PHP variables. The HTML is generated, and sent to the browser, and _then_ JavaScript is run. So if the value is not showing as empty, that's because *it's not empty* - look at the HTML with "View Source" in your browser to see what it has in it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, in the html there is this `<input type="text" class="field-settings" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="">`

but in my template, value contains the variable `$user->first_name`

Comment: Once again **your browser cannot see your template**, it sees only **the HTML generated by that template**. If you echo an empty variable, there is nothing for the JS to see; the HTML when you View Source will be the same as if you hadn't echoed it at all.

Comment: In the previous comment I posted the html that was generated, and the value is null, there is nothing.

Comment: Then your problem is somewhere else. There is no difference between "empty because I never echoed anything" and "empty because I echoed something with no content", both are just empty.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I realized I was applying the js code in the wrong location. Either way it works now.

Answer (score 3):

> variable, so it's not really empty, however the variable can be empty.

what does it mean? print `value` to see what's there. If it's just a 'space' character, use `.trim()`

```
document.getElementById("account_first_name").value.trim();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Forgive my bad explanation, I mean that input value is not empty because it contains the variable $user->first_name. This variable represents the user's first_name which is always empty until the user chooses to enter their name.

var_dump ($user->first_name); shows string(0)"" precisely because the user has not yet chosen a name to enter.

Comment: since your condition is in JavaScript you should do `console.log(document.getElementById("account_first_name").value)` to see what's there, to understand what does it mean 'empty but not empty'.